# Partitioning a Delta Table by a subset of date column

Tags: sql, partitioning, databricks, delta-lake

I am creating a Delta Table in Databricks that contains 1 day worth of proxy logs (100s of millions of lines). I want to be able to partition the table by hour, so simply partitioning the table by '_time' column is not good enough. Also, I am using the `%sql` runtime to create the table in my notebook but I am open to creating it in Scala if that is a better option.

How can I create partition logic such that a new partition is created for each hours worth of logs?

The format of my `_time` column is as follows.

`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.xxxxxx-time:zone` where time and zone are 2 digits.

So, I would like to partition for every unique hour, giving me 24 partitions for a day, like so.

`yyyy-mm-ddThh`

Answer (score 5):

You need to create separate columns on which to partition the dataset. In SQL syntax you can use `date` and `hour` to get values you are interested in and then use it in your query, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE events
USING delta
PARTITIONED BY(date, hour)
AS SELECT *, date(_time) as date, hour(_time) as hour from myData
```

This will result in your delta lake being partitioned by date and hour, physically on disk this will look roughly like:

```
delta/events/date=2019-01-01/
  |-delta/events/date=2019-01-01/hour=0/
  |-delta/events/date=2019-01-01/hour=1/
(...)
delta/events/date=2019-01-02/
(...)
```

Keep in mind this will add those two columns to your delta data, but I can't think of a way to partition by something that's not part of the table (`PARTITION BY hour(x)` won't work).

```
+---+-------------------+----------+----+
| id|              _time|      date|hour|
+---+-------------------+----------+----+
| 71|2019-01-16 12:31:00|2019-01-16|  12|
|108|2019-01-16 12:31:00|2019-01-16|  12|
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to Daniel's (correct) answer, Delta has a new feature for this purpose called "Generated Columns" that allows you to specify derived columns for partitioning, while allowing you to query on the source field, maintaining the performance benefits of the partitions.  When you load your data into a table defined with generated columns, you also won't need to generate/specify the generated columns because Delta already has the definition.

In your case (since you're using Databricks), to create the table, you might do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE events(
id BIGINT,
eventType STRING,
_time TIMESTAMP,
year INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(_time)),
month INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MONTH(_time)),
day INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DAY(_time))
hour INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (HOUR(_time))
)
PARTITIONED BY (eventType, year, month, day, hour)
```

When loading actual data into the table, you won't need to calculate/specify `year`, `month`, `day` or `hour`.

To query this table, you can do...

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE _time >= "2023-03-01 10:00:00" < "2023-03-01 11:00:00"
```

... which will automatically generate a partition filter so that the preceding query only reads the data in the partition `year=2023/month=03/day=01/hour=10`.

If you're using DeltaLake and not Databricks, you can do the same thing, but there's only python/scala syntax for it (that I can find anyway).  See this links for details:

Databricks:

https://docs.databricks.com/delta/generated-columns.html

Delta Lake:

https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#use-generated-columns