# How to partition Delta lake table by Year where I have date in my Delta table

Tags: sql, pyspark, delta-lake

I have a Delta lake table with columns like this.

[image]

I want to partition the table by year.  For that do I need to add year column to my table or can I directly partition by year without creating year column. If so, how do I do that?

Comment: You will need to add that column. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050606/partitioning-a-delta-table-by-a-subset-of-date-column

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment you need to have a column in your data to partition by it.  But in Delta Lake there is a notion of the [generated columns](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/generated-columns.html) when Delta will automatically generate values for a column based on the data from other column(s).

For your case the table declaration will be as following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.people10m (
  id INT,
  name STRING,
  address STRING,
  date date,
  year DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (year(date))
) partitioned by (year)
```